# Experiencing unexpected class behaviour in Python

Tags: python, class

I ran the code below;

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.f = 1

    def __add__(self, x):
        self.f += x
        return self

    def __radd__(self, x):
        self.f += x
        return self
```

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a + 2
<__main__.A object at 0x7f96a90d5700>
>>> a.f == 3
True

# as expected, so far

>>> a = A()
>>> b = A()
>>> a + b
<__main__.A object at 0x7f3d86d7c700>

>>> a.f
<__main__.A object at 0x7f3d86d7cb80>
>>> b.f
2
>>> a.f.f
2
>>> a.f is b
True
```

What just happened? Why is `a.f == b` and `b.f == 2`.

I wonder if this is some definitive behaviour and I didn't explain it properly.

Comment: It's an unusual (non-intuitive) implementation of those operators. Normally, `__add__` should return a new object and not have side effects on the operands. Also, you add the other object `x` directly to the integer attribute `f`. Did you mean: `self.f += x.f`?

Comment: No @Dr.V I meant it exactly that way. Normally it will behave as expected when x is a number. I got that when trying to implement Scala's infix operator using placeholder syntax

Comment: Please provide a *complete* example that other people can test, and make it clear what parts are code and what parts are input or output.

Comment: The shown code wouldn't output anything (except a syntax error because of `some_instance of A`).

Comment: Sorry @KarlKnechtel. I made some mistakes in the code and I've made edits. I think it is clear enough. When ```x``` is a number, the object's ```f``` attribute would simply by incremented as expected.. but things go crazy as shown

Comment: @Ozichukwu no, you *must* provide a [mcve]

Comment: @MichaelButscher That was just a description of the value of ```a.f```. It also shows that ```a.f == b``` below

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've made some edits.. but besides that. How minimal can this thing get? It explains itself already. Take another look pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The line `a + b` calls the `__add__` operator on `a`.
2. The `+=` doesn't work (`int + A`) and hence invokes the `__radd__` on `b`.
3. Here, `b.f` receives the value `2` and returns itself as object.
4. This object is then assigned to `a.f`.

So all as expected, except for the very unusual way of coding.
I hope nobody gets hurt by the code you write.

Even if you insist on your coding, let me (at least for other readers) suggest the *normal* way to define these operators:

```
def __add__(self, x):
    result = A()
    try:
        result.f = self.f + x.f
    except AttributeError:
        result.f = self.f + x
    return result

def __radd__(self, x):
    result = A()
    try:
        result.f = self.f + x.f
    except AttributeError:
        result.f = self.f + x
    return result
```

Now you can calculate `a+b`, `2+a` and `a+2` etc.

Comment: lol.. no one does. I'm not acquainted with the formats of Stack Overflow. Thanks anyway. It's clear now